# Parse JSON File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file stored in the **same folder** as an HTML file for a webpage I'm working on. This HTML file has a script with a function that takes data in a variable in JSON form. I'm having trouble getting the contents of the JSON file into a variable in my HTML file to be used by the function. I am running the HTML file locally.

I've tried the following:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("./data.json", function(jsdata) {
        json = jsdata;
        console.log(json);
    });
});
```

However, it only results in: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file`. Is there any way to parse a local JSON file in Javascript?

The JSON was validated using http://jsonlint.com/

Using "data.json" gives the same error as before.

Comment: Try removing `.` in URL

Comment: It depends on your location of you Javascript file where you call this getJSON function. If the JS code is within the same level of the json file then indeed remove the . other wise ../ should do the trick

Comment: check in tool xrs request and check if file is json valid in validator

Comment: It did no tricks, it laid down on the ground and threw a fit.

Comment: I have validated the JSON file @daremachine

Comment: so check if request is succeed in web tool

Comment: Does it make any difference that I am not hosting the file? I'm running the HTML locally.

Comment: It should be the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a `.`. If the json file is in the same folder as the location your js is running (i.e. your html file), it should be this:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(jsdata) {
        json = jsdata;
        console.log(json);
    });
});
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/grooms/Desktop/SampleTimeline/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You need to run your html from a website - not from the from a directory on the file system. For more info, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Comment: Good to know. I get the noob of the day award.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load a local file using `$.getJSON` in jquery.
You have to set a valid `url` of your file inside of your project, not a local file path because browser prevents it from loading for some security reason.

Answer (score 1):

Dot in the url is causing the problem

Use this:

```
$.getJSON("/data.json", function(jsdata) { 
        json = jsdata;
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1):

The URL provided is wrong.

Use following:

```
$(function () {
    var baseUrl = 'http://....'; // Your base url of app

    // Use the absolute URL in here
    $.getJSON( baseUrl + "/data.json", function (jsdata) {
        json = jsdata;
        console.log(json);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./data.json", // or "/data.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
})
```